# How to send taged message over ZeroMQ in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, zeromq

So having [official wrapper](https://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq) I try to create a simple publisher that would be capable of topic based messages publishing (alike [publisher demonstrated here for python](https://gist.github.com/minrk/4667957)):

```
using (var context = ZmqContext.Create())
using (var pub = context.CreateSocket(SocketType.PUB))
{
    pub.Bind(url);
    while (true)
    {
        pub.Send( // How to send "Message" string on topic "A.message"?
    }
}
```

So how to send "Message" string on topic/with tag "`A.message`"?

Answer (score 0):

In ZeroMQ, a message's topic is just the start of the message.  In your publisher, try sending messages with the prefix `A.message`.